# Trying to get the filtered stock return using a standard GARCH(1,1) model

Tags: r, time-series, filtering

I am trying to get the filtered stock return using a standard GARCH(1,1) model.
My data sometimes has some missing values inevitably, so I also impose the "na.omit" function on top of the data class I have where the full code is shown as below:

```
 spec1 = ugarchspec(variance.model = list(model = "sGARCH", garchOrder = c(1,1)))
 sgarch.fit2 = ugarchfit(spec = spec1,data = na.omit(data[,1]))
 sgarch.fit2@fit$fitted.values
```

Does this give out the GARCH(1,1) fitted stock return values I expect?

```
> dput(data[,1])
c(0.066213252, 0.043896818, NA, 0.384139127, -0.229078336, 0.318704285, 
NA, 0.062993697, 0.517381475, -0.05973511, -0.119688702, 0.040537601, 
0.04039708, 0.020126307, -0.275374066, 0.143848804, -0.234350097, 
-0.104515758, -0.021171201, -0.349291363, 0.131242113, -0.150452546, 
-0.021928287, -0.065803658, 0.022112634, -0.131592525, -0.022306129, 
0.133999714, 0.3471199, 1.398019855, -0.268292496, 0.105076458, 
0.155925617, NA, -0.697393256, 0.611919091, 1.271320715, -0.118125665, 
0.527573029, -0.674749652, 0.137590932, -0.238182357, -0.856083531, 
-1.208982356, 1.307752531, 0.017086142, -0.799467791, -1.142493046, 
0.981510737, 0.910969474, 1.177797522, -0.160468573, 0.432429871, 
-0.439114907, -0.13085608, -0.842182438, 0.504325538, -0.497878437, 
-0.786782987, -0.591016955, 0.518225263, 0.391786747, 0.051797767, 
-0.30174573, 0.105870401, 0.432203153, 0.859987458, -0.450600527, 
0.002427649, -0.417616519, 0.439261031, 1.055868989, 0.469365816, 
0.461224417, 0.58485912, -0.764848343, 0.422595892, -0.116240653, 
0.044017395, -0.764303382, -0.875930179, 1.302239577, 0.237244734, 
-0.239951924, 0.796885884, 1.111999435, 1.224969922, -0.713564809, 
-0.65554154, -0.343346094, -0.296716925, -0.77485319, -0.638164493, 
-0.78261012, 1.262776039, -0.309687033, -0.055914949, 0.581277608, 
0.840932106, 0.180139297, 0.721169742, 0.143596578, 0.787902392, 
0.39904866, 0.916224199, 0.023280009, 0.321346954, 0.668854159, 
0.807859782, 0.837538958, 0.288266224, 0.153651807, 0.237704789, 
-0.009022188, -0.336498601, 0.736785641, 0.465574309, 0.931153666, 
0.30317225, -0.398256275, 0.862119724, -0.236530507, -0.721493588, 
0.699137962, 0.397608925, 0.176846374, 0.733554988, -0.116055798, 
-0.281757301, 0.465389809, 0.459752802, -0.278716687, 1.011047095, 
-0.50133047, -0.13325299, -0.755349549, -0.125024314, 0.303016423, 
0.503110895, 0.45275188, 0.858508495, 0.35536308, 0.609849503, 
0.314152096, -0.623775814, 0.430279968, 0.143645553, -0.141167735, 
-0.099526192, -0.446207489, -0.454168777, 0.056967645, 0.528456322, 
-0.99470345, -0.264620991, -1.365124742, 0.676457392, 0.699847635, 
1.220610126, 0.329119891, -1.268694744, 0.48358095, -0.076055818, 
-1.178739331, -1.468289565, -1.11894726, -0.858476819, -1.38272861, 
-1.446655024, 1.538860399, 1.398895284, 0.672846909, 1.105483814, 
1.418549802, 1.328472156, 0.377473759, -0.918571657, -0.176211244, 
-0.419320374, 0.629758114, 0.038031338, 1.075886664, 0.860331102, 
-1.075344494, -0.938432799, 1.239594266, -0.714355796, 0.293268278, 
0.972055976, -0.720609518, 1.232763464, 0.466147357, 0.502195779, 
-0.70773847, -0.460216833, 0.178668454, 0.485552171, -0.763547796, 
-1.348637295, -1.342376438, -1.268700152, -1.23063675, 0.638264308, 
1.374931072, 1.065623148, -0.804937215, 0.070767334, -1.273761967, 
0.726680623, -0.166131707, 0.88435225, 0.82009227, 1.035543215, 
1.236053554, 0.665985266, 0.361008893, -0.051626243, -1.024100581, 
0.917213941, 0.579379759, -1.240269608, 1.052650788, 0.666604148, 
-0.411446102, 1.015536568, -0.029131751, -0.256028039, 0.698933417, 
-0.52129114, -0.39588291, -0.280415063, 0.586995599, -0.740852605, 
-1.24754494, 0.165950264, -0.725812208, 1.056567213, 0.751073606, 
-1.011993081, -0.00605583, 1.348097702, -0.237397259, 0.98601247, 
0.458209107, -0.397866489, 0.741851428, -0.305922869, -0.264591678, 
0.322728851, 0.874585789, -0.052072185, -0.756458209, -0.989722621, 
0.461477399, 0.197229434, -0.469059271, -1.166653076, 1.235861982, 
0.666747712, 0.519958772, 0.84850821, -0.810653446, 0.648620438, 
0.131735052, -0.275670518, 1.013780032, 0.773522424, -0.182691827, 
0.428388085, 0.525670052, 0.125951591, 0.338583664, 0.109929127, 
-0.075597096, -0.171640623, 1.069261732, 0.387127118, -0.301056415, 
-0.057008725, -1.032754678, 0.022862688, 0.38494689, -0.736364097, 
0.491872298, 0.071650091, -0.359687261, -1.199780071, 0.516148826, 
0.907407421, -0.170122244, 0.880619265, -0.980487011, 0.32150948, 
-0.071215566, -0.907686793, 0.413909697, 0.489582713, 0.301281935, 
0.371661805, -0.137957899, -0.667432513, -1.487930215, 1.255081046, 
-0.035225982, 0.644565392, -0.908489138, 0.797808762, -1.040785704, 
-0.190159439, 1.482278914, 0.395773562, 0.144569632, 0.81661841, 
0.642524314, 0.271137083, 1.12786281, -0.788354505, 0.619460335, 
0.399011655, 1.076257823, -0.287282425, 0.707711451, 0.748627235, 
-0.033779348, -1.324036167, 0.390745829, -0.942384295, -0.250815315, 
-1.197993289, 0.238927848, -0.858417288, 0.082926469, 0.961932308, 
1.284410627, 0.117991803, 1.221247474, 0.730988352, -1.235110033, 
0.803225616, -0.792001494, 0.646110442, 0.742796753, -0.453255147, 
-0.052919612)
```